# How to overload constructors in kotlin differs in lambda return type

Tags: lambda, kotlin, constructor-overloading

I have two constructors which are different only in their lambda return type. Is there any option how to overload them? I was trying to use **JvmOverloads** annotation, but it didn't work.

```
constructor(db : Database, handler: ( transaction: Transaction) -> Unit) : this(db, Handler<Transaction>( {handler.invoke(it)}))

@JvmOverloads
constructor(db : Database, handler: ( transaction: Transaction) -> Any) : this(db, Handler<Transaction>( {handler.invoke(it)}))
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot define constructors with signatures that differ only in generic parameters (in your case, it's generic parameters for `Function1<in P1, out R>`) because the signatures would clash after generics erasure.

However, in your case `Unit` is subtype of `Any`, and since `Function<in P1, out R>` [is covariant on `R`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), you can pass a function that returns `Unit` to the second constructor, so just remove the first one.

Simplified example:

```
class C(val action: (Int) -> Any)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f: (Int) -> Unit = { println(it) }
    C(f)
}
```

For more complicated cases, [consider changing to factory functions](https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide/issues/22): unlike constructors, you can annotate them with [`@JvmName`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-name/) to avoid the signatures clash:

```
@JvmName("createCUnit")
fun createC(f: (Int) -> Unit) = C(f)

fun createC(f: (Int) -> Any) = C(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

When targeting JVM backend, all Kotlin classes are compiled to JVM bytecode. The problem with java's bytecode is [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). This means that all info about generics is removed (it's Java's issue not Kotlin's).

Declaring functional type `(transaction: Transaction) -> Unit` is eqivalent to using this type: `Function1<Transaction, Unit>`. However, for JVM bytecode both `Function1<Transaction, Unit>` and `Function1<Transaction, Any>` are the same.

This means that both your constructors have the same signature in JVM world.

You can "simulate" constructors using `companion object`

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(db: Database, h: Handler<Transaction>)

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(db: Database, handler: (transaction: Transaction) -> Unit) = MyClass(db, Handler<Transaction>({ handler.invoke(it) }))

        @JvmName("alternative_constructor")
        operator fun invoke(db: Database, handler: (transaction:     Transaction) -> Any) = MyClass(db, Handler<Transaction>({ handler.invoke(it) }))
    }
}
```

And usage looks like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val db = Database()

    MyClass(db, Handler {  }) //real constructor
    MyClass(db){ } //version from companion object
}
```